# Concatenate the files downloaded by wget

Tags: wget

I download multiple BibTeX entries using `wget <list of links>`. Is there a way to concatenate all these entries into a single .bib file on the same command (i.e. *without* storing the files separately and then doing `cat *.bib >> mybib.bib`)?

Answer (score 0):

Use `wget`'s `-O` option:

```
wget -O everything_concatenated.bib <list of links>
```